# R frequency table based on presence / absence samples

Tags: r

I wasn´t quite sure how to search for the topic I´m interested in, so I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked. Questions related to frequency table didn´t solve my doubt.

I have the following df, where `1` indicates a positive results and `2` a negative ones:

```
d1 <- data.frame( Household = c(1:5), State = c("AL","AL","AL","MI","MI"), Electricity = c(1,1,1,2,2),
Fuelwood = c(2,2,1,1,1))
```

I want to produce a frequency table where I can identify the percentage of people using Eletricity, Fuelwood and Electricity+Fuelwood, such as `df2`:

```
d2 <- data.frame (State = c("AL", "MI"), Electricity = c(66.6,0), Fuelwood = c(0,100), ElectricityANDFuelwood = c(33.3,0))
```

Please consider that my real df has approx. 42 k households, 5 energy sources and 27 states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can look for rows in `d1` where `Electricity` and `Fuelwood` are positive (`1`).  Using that logical index, we can change the values in `Electricity` and `Fuelwood` rows that are both positive to negative or `2`.  Then, create an additional column `ElecticityANDFuelwood` using the `index` that was created.  Change from `wide` to `long` form using `melt`, subset only the two columns `State` and `variable`, use `table` and `prop.table` to calculate the frequency and relative frequency.

```
indx <- with(d1, Electricity==1 & Fuelwood==1)

d1[indx,3:4] <- 2
dT <- transform(d1, ElectricityANDFuelwood= (indx)+0)[-1]

library(reshape2)
dT1 <- subset(melt(dT, id.var='State'), value==1, select=1:2)
round(100*prop.table(table(dT1), margin=1),2)
 #      variable
#State Electricity Fuelwood ElectricityANDFuelwood
#  AL       66.67     0.00                  33.33
#  MI        0.00   100.00                   0.00
```

Or a `data.table` solution contributed by @David Arenburg

```
library(data.table)
d2 <- as.data.table(d1[-1])[, ElectricityANDFuelwood := 
             (Electricity == 1 & Fuelwood == 1)]
d2[(ElectricityANDFuelwood), (2:3) := 2]
d2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 100*sum(x == 1)/.N), by = State]  
#   State Electricity Fuelwood ElectricityANDFuelwood
#1:    AL    66.66667        0               33.33333
#2:    MI     0.00000      100                0.00000
```

Comment: You could probably do something similar with `data.table` though not sure if it would be more efficient `library(data.table);
d2 <- as.data.table(d1[-1])[, ElectricityANDFuelwood := (Electricity == 1 & Fuelwood == 1)];
d2[ElectricityANDFuelwood == TRUE, (2:3) := 2];
d2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == 1)/.N), by = State]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, I was working on the `data.table` solution while you shared this.  I will post this.  The `(2:3) := 2` is completely new for me. Very nice.

Comment: Should I change the tittle so the post can be useful to more people? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Gil33 `(2:3)` denotes the columns `Electricity` and `Fuelwood` in the `d2` dataset.  `(ElectricityANDFuelwood)` is logical index.  So, here we are assigning the `2 and 3rd` column rows that are true for the logical index to `negative` or `2`.  You could change the title if you think that a more suitable option is available with you.